# Expected value for geometric probability

Tags: probability, expectation

Points $P=(X_P,Y_P)$ and $Q=(X_Q,Y_Q)$ were independently chosen from square $(-1,0),(0,-1),(1,0),(0,1)$ with geometric probability. How does one find $$\mathbb{E}\big|X_P-X_Q\big|^2\ ?$$

I've been thinking and thinking, but couldn't come up with anything. How do you even define expected value here? There's no density function, nor is the distribution discrete.

Comment: Are you sure about ['geometric probability'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)?

Comment: Not with geometria distribution, but with geometric probability. That is classical probability, but instead of finding $\frac{\#A}{\# \Omega}$ we look for volume or any other kind of measure of the set $A$.

Comment: "There's no density function" Why do you think so?

Comment: Then there is a density function.

Comment: Oh, that's nice.

Comment: It is constant and positive on the square, and $0$ 'out of the square'. Can you find it?

Comment: So it means it is a uniform distribution, just like that? (uniform on the square)

Comment: Yes, uniform on the square, but be sure to note that the square sides are not parallel to the axes and so $X_P$ and $Y_P$ ditto $X+Q$ and $Y_Q)$ are not independent random variables (even though the pairs $(X_P, Y_Q)$ and $(X_Q,Y_Q)$ are independent random vectors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By independence, $A=E((X_P-X_Q)^2)$ is $A=E(X_P^2)+E(X_Q^2)-2E(X_P)E(X_Q)$. Since $X_P$ and $X_Q$ are identically distributed, $A=2E(X_P^2)-2E(X_P)^2$. The density of $X_P$ is $f:x\mapsto(1-|x|)^+$ and $f$ is even hence $E(X_P)=0$ and $E(X_P^2)=2\displaystyle\int_0^1x^2(1-x)\mathrm dx=\tfrac16$ and $A=2\cdot\frac16=\frac13$.

Comment: The problem was to find this density function. I don't see it yet, but I'll think about it. Thanks.

Comment: @Jules Draw a picture of the square.

Comment: I think I got it. It's x-axis_including_our_point : x-axis ratio? (well... more or less)